# My clock has disappeared

Tags: app-widgets, htc-sense

I have a HTC Desire X running Android 4.0.4 (not rooted).

I use the "Digital Clock" widget which comes with phone on my home screen. The phone came with 3 clock related widgets - Weather Clock, Digital Clock and Social Clock. By default, the Weather Clock appeared on the home screen but I removed that from the Home Screen and added the Digital Clock on the home screen. This was good for a month.

But today, the Digital Clock disappeared from the home screen.

I tried adding the clock back to the home screen from the Widgets list.
I am able to add "Social Clock" and it's visible on the home screen. But I am unable to add "Digital Clock" and "Weather Clock". When I add either of this - it takes me to the chose a City menu & then when I chose a city, it returns me to an empty home screen with no Clock. I am however able to add the "Social Clock".

I tried the following things

- Booted the phone
- I force stopped and cleared data for Clock and Clock Widget
  None of this helped.

What do I do? I am not really a Social Clock kind of guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a reset from "backup and reset" menu in settings. And this got the Digital Clock back.